# await inside a forEach block in Node.js 14.x AWS lambda code

Tags: aws-lambda, async-await

I have an AWS Lambda function in Node.js 14.x that is triggered by SQS and the code needs to process the data and re-publish to a mqtt topic. This is the code I have using async(event);

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});


var iotParams = {
  topic: 'my-channel',
  qos: 0
};

export const handler = async(event) => {
 
  var msgBody;  

  event.Records.forEach(record => {
    const { body } = record;
    msgBody = body;
    console.log(msgBody);
    
    // for each record, publish the data
      
  
  });
  
  // publish the data
  iotParams.payload = Buffer.from(msgBody);  
  var iotPromise = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: 'a1ilxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'}).publish(iotParams).promise();

  // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
  iotPromise.then(
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(
      function(err) {
      console.error(err, err.stack);
    }
  );  
  await iotPromise;  

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };
  return response;
};
```

Since the SQS can pass multiple records (in an array) to lambda, I have to parse and publish the data for each record. So in the above code, I tried to move the mqtt publish code to inside the forEach() loop, but lambda complains about the await inside this loop.
What would be the right way to achieve this? I'm not very familiar with async calls...

Thanks in advance
Gus

Comment: Sabina, We can’t use `await` inside of a forEach loop because `forEach` is not promise-aware and will not wait for your promises right?

Comment: Amith, I don't know that.. That's why I ask the right way to accomplish this..

Comment: *"but lambda complains about the await inside this loop"*: you provided code that does not have an await inside a loop. Please provide the code that has the problem. Also, you are overwriting `msgBody` with `msgBody = body;` in each iteration of the loop. Is that really what you want? And if the function is called with an array, then what should the returned response be? Also an array? There seems no code in your attempt that deals with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for...of` instead of `forEach` in asynchronous code.

You can read [this](https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/37d2085425c049629b80956d3c618971) to learn more.